# From sequence of sets to sequence decreasing of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of sets.

Is it possible starting from $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to define a decreasing sequence of sets $\{B_n\}_n$?

If it is possible, how is it done?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the $B_n$ sets supposed to be the $A_n$ sets except ordered?  If not, if you just want to create a decreasing sequence of sets from the $A_n$ sets, you can use the intersection.  Start with $B_1= A_1$, then $B_2= B_1\cap A_2$, $B_3= B_2\cap A_3$, and in general, $B_n= B_{n-1}A_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but perhaps that what you are aiming at is$$B_n=\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_j.$$

Comment: Thanks! At this point, can we say that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_{n}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that's a correct statement.

Answer (score 2):

We define $$\{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$ as $$ B_n = A_n$$

$$B_{n+1} = B_n \cap A_{n+1}$$

$$B_{n+2} = B_{n+1} \cap A_{n+2}$$
$$B_{n+3} = B_{n+2} \cap A_{n+3}$$

and so forth, $$B_{n+k} = B_{n+k-1} \cap A_{n+k}$$